# Type Mismatch Error while looping the array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build the array by looping the data set.

Values inside are Object/Range type. (e.g. 34FF544)

I get the "type mismatch" error.

```
Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim y As Long
Dim eil As Long

eil = 1
y = 1

Do Until Sheets(2).Range("A" & eil) = ""   'looping until the blank cell
arr2(y) = Range("A" & eil)                 'storing the value in an array

y = y + 1                                  'next array element
eil = eil + 1                              'next row to take value from
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are currently populating an array is dynamic and for that you need to adjust two things:

- > "By declaring a dynamic array, you can size the array while the code
  >   is running. Use a Static, Dim, Private, or Public statement to declare
  >   an array, leaving the parentheses empty."[Office Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-arrays)

  So make sure you start your code with `Dim arr2() As Variant`
- The second thing is that because you use a dynamic array, you have the option to resize the array before your loop, however you can also resize your array on the go, which is your route:

  ```
  Do Until Sheets(2).Range("A" & eil) = ""
      ReDim Preserve arr2(y) 'This is your key!
      arr2(y) = Range("A" & eil)                 
      y = y + 1
      eil = eil + 1
  Loop
  ```

Now that you know the culprit, it's also good to have a look at how sufficient your code actually is. Few things that come to mind:

- You have both `y` and `eil` going on the same count, why not just use one of them?
- You can just load your array from a range in one go
- Also, you should look into naming your worksheet and run code through a `With... End With`

Comment: Hey, thanks for all this info.
I'm using y to load the array each time and eil is a different variable that goes through hundreds of rows. It's just a small part of the whole code I've got.